# Autoauthuser not resetting expiration of token

Tags: angular

I have a function that I made from a tutorial that is supposed to re-authenticate the user in order to reset expiration of token. I put `this.authService.autoAuthUser();` in ngOnInit() in most of pages. While working in my app, It will automatically log me out even though I'm an active user so the autoauth doesn't appear to be working, but I"m not sure why. I appreciate any help!

auth.service.ts

```
import { Injectable, OnDestroy } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient, HttpParams } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Router } from "@angular/router";

import { AuthData } from "./auth-data.model";
import { AuthDataLogin } from "./auth-data-login.model";
import { LoginService } from "./login/login.service";
import { VerifyEmail } from "./verify.model";
import { Subject } from "rxjs";
import { ToastrService } from "ngx-toastr";
import { takeUntil, switchMap } from "rxjs/operators";
import { SignupModel } from "./artist-signup/signup-model";

@Injectable({ providedIn: "root" })
export class AuthService implements OnDestroy {
  private isAuthenticated = false;
  private token: string;
  private tokenTimer: any;
  private userName: string;
  private authStatusListener = new Subject<boolean>();
  private userId: string;
  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private router: Router,
    private loginService: LoginService,
    private toastr: ToastrService
  ) {}

  username: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();
  destroy = new Subject();

  getUsername() {
    return this.username;
  }

  getToken() {
    return this.token;
  }

  getIsAuth() {
    return this.isAuthenticated;
  }

  getUserId() {
    return this.userId;
  }
  getAuthStatusListener() {
    return this.authStatusListener.asObservable();
  }

  createUser(user: SignupModel) {
    const authData: AuthData = {
      email: user.email,
      password: user.password,
      username: user.username,
      phoneNumber: user.phoneNumber,
      over21: user.over21,
      role: user.role,
      fullName: "Not Added Yet",
      address1: "none",
      address2: "none",
      city: "none",
      state: "none",
      zip: "none"
    };
    console.log(user);
    return this.http.post("http://localhost:3000/api/user/signup", authData);
  }


  login(email: string, password: string) {
    const authData: AuthDataLogin = { email: email, password: password };
    return this.http
      .post<{
        token: string;
        expiresIn: number;
        userId: string;
        username: string;
      }>("http://localhost:3000/api/user/login", authData)
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy))
      .subscribe(response => {
        const token = response.token;

        this.userName = response.instagramName;

        this.token = token;
        if (token) {
          const expiresInDuration = response.expiresIn;
          this.setAuthTimer(expiresInDuration);
          this.isAuthenticated = true;
          this.userId = response.userId;
          this.userName = response.instagramName;
          this.authStatusListener.next(true);
          const now = new Date();
          const expirationDate = new Date(
            now.getTime() + expiresInDuration * 1000
          );
          this.saveAuthData(token, expirationDate, this.userId);
          this.router.navigate(["/listings"]);
          this.username.next(response.instagramName);
        }
      });
  }


  autoAuthUser() {
    const authInformation = this.getAuthData();
    if (!authInformation) {
      return;
    }
    const now = new Date();
    const expiresIn = authInformation.expirationDate.getTime() - now.getTime();
    if (expiresIn > 0) {
      this.token = authInformation.token;
      this.isAuthenticated = true;
      this.userId = authInformation.userId;
      this.setAuthTimer(expiresIn / 1000);
      this.authStatusListener.next(true);
    }
  }

  logout() {
    this.token = null;
    this.isAuthenticated = false;
    this.authStatusListener.next(false);
    clearTimeout(this.tokenTimer);
    this.clearAuthData();
    this.userId = null;
    this.router.navigate(["/login"]);
  }

  private setAuthTimer(duration: number) {
    this.tokenTimer = setTimeout(() => {
      this.logout();
    }, duration * 1000);
  }

  private saveAuthData(token: string, expirationDate: Date, userId: string) {
    localStorage.setItem("token", token);
    localStorage.setItem("expiration", expirationDate.toISOString());
    localStorage.setItem("userId: ", userId);
    localStorage.setItem("username", this.userName);
  }

  private clearAuthData() {
    localStorage.removeItem("token");
    localStorage.removeItem("expiration");
    localStorage.removeItem("userId");
    localStorage.removeItem("username");
  }

  private getAuthData() {
    const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
    const expirationDate = localStorage.getItem("expiration");
    const userId = localStorage.getItem("userId: ");
    if (!token || !expirationDate) {
      return;
    }
    return {
      token: token,
      expirationDate: new Date(expirationDate),
      userId: userId
    };
  }
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.destroy.next();
    this.destroy.complete();
    this.username.next();
    this.username.complete();
    clearTimeout(this.tokenTimer);
  }
}
```

auth-guard.ts

```
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, Router } from "@angular/router";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { AuthService } from "./auth.service";

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate
{
constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) {}

canActivate(
  route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  state: RouterStateSnapshot,
  ): boolean | Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> {
    const isAuth = this.authService.getIsAuth();
    if (!isAuth) {
      this.router.navigate(['/login']);
    }
    return isAuth;
  }
}
```

Comment: Where is a call of `setAuthTimer`, who calls `clearTimeout`?
If you are automatically logged out in a second, then check the value passed to `setAuthTimer` as it is the only function which calls `logout`.

Comment: I think you misunderstood. I could be working for a period of time and I randomly get signed out. Since I'm an active user ```this.authService.autoAuthUser():``` in ngOnInit() is supposed to reset the timer everytime I load a component. I'm not logging in and getting logged out immediately. The timer just never gets new time so it just expires from initial login

Comment: Can you show code of components which use the service?

Comment: The components don't do anything with authService but ```this.authUser.getUserId()```   ```this.authService.autoAuthUser()``` inside ngOnInit. Also there's like 15 components, but here's one as an example: https://pastebin.com/myySrUfy

Comment: Try to add `console.log` to `autoAuthUser`, see the value of `expiresIn`, see where `navigate(['/login'])` is called except the `logout` method, and so on.

Comment: It gets called from authguard which is being used with the router module. For example ```{  path: "messages", component: MessageTableComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },```
when the timer runs out, this is most likely whats redirecting me to login. I added authguard.ts above

Answer (score 0):

Please rewrite `setAuthTimer` (wait just 10 seconds and add logging):

```
  private setAuthTimer(duration: number) {
    this.tokenTimer = setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('Logging out in setAuthTimer');
      this.logout();
    }, 10);
  }
```

add logging to `AuthGuard`:

```
 canActivate(
      route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
      state: RouterStateSnapshot,
      ): boolean | Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> {
        const isAuth = this.authService.getIsAuth();
        if (!isAuth) {
          console.log('Logging out in AuthGuard');
          this.router.navigate(['/login']);
        }
        return isAuth;
  }
```

We'll find out who really navigates to `/login` route this way.

UPDATE

Each time you load your component `autoAuthUser` is called. But you never clear your timer by calling `clearTimeout`. Put it at the beginning of `autoAuthUser`, or call `ngOnDestroy` also at the beginning.

```
 autoAuthUser() {
    clearTimeout(this.tokenTimer);
    // or call this.ngOnDestroy();

    const authInformation = this.getAuthData();
    if (!authInformation) {
      return;
    }
    const now = new Date();
    const expiresIn = authInformation.expirationDate.getTime() - now.getTime();
    if (expiresIn > 0) {
      this.isAuthenticated = true;
      this.authStatusListener.next(true);

      this.token = authInformation.token;      
      this.userId = authInformation.userId;

      this.setAuthTimer(expiresIn / 1000);
    }
  }
```

UPDATE 2

As you call method `getAuthData`, then your `autoAuthUser` should be called after `login` is called, because `login` method calls `saveAuthData`. If you want to reset your timer (which is not correct) then just do this

```
autoAuthUser() {
      clearTimeout(this.tokenTimer);
      this.setAuthTimer(this.expiresInDuration);
      console.log("INSIDE autoAuthUser(): " + this.expiresInDuration + ' sec');
    }
  }
```

Comment: ```Logging out in setAuthTimer``` outputs to console after it logs out right after logging in

Comment: So it works as expected with 10 seconds. Try to remove 10 seconds and set `duration` instead and see what outputs to console then. Also add logging of duration.

Comment: I think this is what you're asking https://pastebin.com/zstuzzDA   it outputted: ```Duration is 131``` sometimes it's 150 when I log in. Somewhere around there each time

Comment: Is 131 and 150 what you really stored?

Comment: You removed `console.log('Logging out in setAuthTimer');` Now how are you sure that you redirected to `/login` page from `setAuthTimer` function?

Comment: So your problem is that you are redirected in 131 seconds. But that is the value what you store in `login` function. I don't think it is a bug. Are you sure it working incorrectly?

Comment: Maybe I don't fully understand it. I built it from a tutorial. I thought putting this.authService.authAuthUser() would reset the logout time. It doesn't log me out in 131 seconds. It usually takes about 30 mins or so while developing within the app. How can I make it so that it resets the timer when I visit a page if this is incorrect?

Comment: @Andy Since `AuthService` is a service with a provider injected in the root module, method `ngOnDestroy` won't be called (I think unless you reload a page). So your timer is never cleared.
If you need to reset your timer when you call `autoAuthUser`, then either put `clearTimeout(this.tokenTimer);` at the beginning of the method, or `this.ngOnDestroy()`. 
Thus, your timer will be cleared first, and  then `setAuthTimer` will read `expiresIn` value from `localStorage` and will call `setTimeout`.

Comment: I've been playing for the last day and it's definitely still logging me out while using the app. I tried this.ngOnDestroy() and clearTimeout(this.tokenTimer) as so: https://pastebin.com/rSuv8WqG    Perhaps I misunderstood you

Comment: Of course it's logging you out. Does the period, over which  it logs you out, equal to `expiresIn` value you logged in `autoAuthUser`?

Comment: The period of time I have before being logged out appears to be unchanged from what I can tell.

Comment: If it logs you out over `expiresIn` value then there  is no bug. Otherwise I don't understand what you want.

Comment: I don't want a user to be using the site and randomly get signed out as they actively use it. So I figure it makes sense to reset the expiresIn time whenever they visit a page since they are actively using the site. That's why I was trying ```this.authService.autoAuthUser()``` on ngOnit(). I thought this would accomplish it, but I guess not. So how can I reset the clock on expiresIn when a page loads?

Comment: @Andy, now the problem is that your `expiresIn` value is too low so an user is logged out too quickly. Try to log in and see value of `expiresInDuration`. That is add `console.log('Login: ' + expiresInDuration);` after `const expiresInDuration = response.expiresIn;` in `login` method. Do this first, and then we'll finish your problem.

Comment: I added the console.log. ```Login: 3600```

Comment: So it should log you out in an hour. If it is too small value for you, that is strange, because a server decides what value is sent to a client side (to you). If you still want to reset your timer, then memorize `expiresInDurationSec`, i.e. create a field `expiresInDurationSec: number;` and add code to `login` function `this.expiresInDurationSec = expiresInDuration;` Then your `autoAuthUser` should take 2 lines of code: `clearTimer(this.tokenTimer); setAuthTimer(this.expiresInDurationSec);`

Comment: I added the code, but what I don't understand it I probably did it wrong is isn't this  ```this.setAuthTimer(expiresIn / 1000);``` This line seems to conflict with the ```this.setAuthTimer(this.expiresInDuration);```  Here's my updated code https://pastebin.com/SseV47nD

Comment: @Andy, no, your variant of method `autoAuthUser` isn't right. See UPDATE 2 in the answer.

Comment: I've been testing it and it doesn't seem to be working still. I have this.authUser.authAuthUser() in my ngOninit on my main page and if I click off the page and come back to it then console.log output ```INSIDE autoAuthUser()3547.821``` gets lower and lower every time I come back to page. It never resets

Comment: @Andy, it can't get lower unless you reassign a value to `this.expiresInDuration`. Agree?

Comment: Yes 100%. My mistake. I had another console.log that was throwing me off that said ```console.log("INSIDE autoAuthUser()" + expiresIn / 1000)``` But it still does log me out with this code: https://pastebin.com/PBWpAbda

Comment: You have a wrong `autoAuthUser` implementation. Look at UPDATE 2 in my answer. The body of the function must be `clearTimeout(this.tokenTimer); this.setAuthTimer(this.expiresInDuration); console.log("INSIDE autoAuthUser(): " + this.expiresInDuration + " sec");` Just 3 lines of code.